# Using d3.interpolateString for a MM:SS transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working with d3 to try and get a time to properly transition from one state to another. I am aware that `d3.interpolateString` picks out numbers that can be interpolated from the passed in string.

I am working with a time in the format MM:SS. What has been happening is that the numbers when being interpolated end up being converted to decimal in the transition. In addition, an example of a final state of 09:02 will result with just a result of 9:2, since it seems to remove the zeros.

Here is what I have been working with so far:

```
// selector - d3 selector
function setupStringInterpolation(selector, duration, text){
    selector
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .tween("string", function(){
            var node = d3.select(this),
            i = d3.interpolate(node.text(), text);
            return function(t){
                node.text(i(t));
            }
        });
}
```

This fiddle should make more sense of it: https://jsfiddle.net/wwwykmk8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went a slightly different route to achieve this. I'm using `d3.interpolateDate` so we can deal directly with date objects and using `d3.timeFormat` to only output the `minute` and `second` part of the `date` object.

```
var d1 = new Date("2015-03-25");
d1.setMinutes(0);
d1.setSeconds(0);
var d2 = new Date("2015-03-25");
d2.setMinutes(9);
d2.setSeconds(2);

function setupStringInterpolation(selector, duration, text){
    var format = d3.timeFormat("%M:%S");
        selector
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .tween("string", function(){
                var node = d3.select(this),
                i = d3.interpolateDate(d1, text);
                return function(t){
                    node.text(format(i(t)));
                }
            });
}

var finalValue = "01-01-2017";
setupStringInterpolation(d3.select("#timeSpot"), 1500, d2);
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9w5km9sx/

Comment: Tweaked jsfiddle to use more appropriate start/end dates (same date), and a d3.format object for formatting: https://jsfiddle.net/rtq1xkmq/

Comment: @searlea That looks more appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolate).

> d3.interpolate(a, b)
>
> Returns an interpolator between the two arbitrary values a and b. The interpolator implementation is based on the type of the end value b, using the following algorithm:
>
> ...If b is a
> **number**, use interpolateNumber.
> ...If b is a **date**, use interpolateDate.

If you want an interpolator between 9:00 and 9:20 on a particular day then you would need to pass in a date objects as arguments. You could convert the text to date objects.

Guy above beat me to it but this is what i altered for your code:

```
function setupStringInterpolation(selector, duration, text){
        selector
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .tween("string", function(){
                var node = d3.select(this);
                var nodeText = node.text();
                var format = d3.timeFormat("%M:%S");
                startDate = new Date().setHours(nodeText.substr(0,2),nodeText.substr(3));
                endDate = new Date().setHours(text.substr(0,2),text.substr(3));
                var i = d3.interpolate(startDate,endDate);

                return function(t){
                    node.text(format(i(t)));
                }
            });
}

var finalValue = "09:02";
setupStringInterpolation(d3.select("#timeSpot"), 1500, finalValue);
```

The fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wwwykmk8/